# Android - ScrollView with TextView auto scrolling

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, scrollview

I have a TextView within a ScrollView, which currently scrolls to the bottom of the TextView.

The TextView is filled dynamically constantly updating (the TextView is essentially acting as an actions console).

However, the problem I am having is that when the dynamic text is added to the ScrollView, the user can scroll past the text into black space, which is increasing everytime more content is added to the TextView.

I have tried various different apporaches however none of these gave the right outcome. I cannot use maxLines or define height of the layouts as I need this to be dynamic for the various screen sizes, which the number of lines visible constantly changing.

I had also orginally done this progromatically, however this was crashing at random time and therefore would like to keep it in my layout (better usabilty), example code below:

```
final int scrollAmount = update.getLayout().getLineTop(update.getLineCount()) - update.getHeight();
if(scrollAmount > 0)
{
    update.scrollTo(0, scrollAmount);
}
```

The code below is my current layout xml being used to automatically scroll my TextView to the bottom as content is added:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/spacer2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spacer1"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/battle_details"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

EDIT - This is the code I am using to add text to my TextView:

```
private void CreateConsoleString()
{
    TextView update = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.battle_details);
    String ConsoleString = "";
    // BattleConsole is an ArrayList<String>
    for(int i = 0; i < BattleConsole.size(); i++)
    {
        ConsoleString += BattleConsole.get(i) + "\n";
    }
    update.setText(ConsoleString);
}
```

EDIT 2 - I add content to the BattleConsole like this:

```
BattleConsole.add("Some console text was added");
CreateConsoleString();
```

To sum up my only issue is the ScrollView and/or TextView is adding blank space to the bottom rather than stop the user from scrolling at the last line of text. Any help or guidence as to where I am going wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you adding new line characters with the text? Show us the code where you update the `TextView` please.

Comment: Please see edited question with code snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that when you call

```
BattleConsole.get(i)
```

it sometimes returns an empty `String` so you are just basically adding new lines to your `TextView`.

You can do this for example:

```
StringBuilder consoleString = new StringBuilder();
// I'm using a StringBuilder here to avoid creating a lot of `String` objects
for(String element : BattleConsole) {
    // I'm assuming element is not null
    if(!"".equals(element)) {
        consoleString.append(element);
        consoleString.append(System.getProperty("line.separator")); // I'm using a constant here.
    }
}
update.setText(consoleString.toString());
```

If you could post the code of `BattleConsole` I could help you more.

*As a footnote: it is encouraged to use camelCase in java. Only class names start with capital letters in java according to the convention.*

Comment: I have implemented your StringBuilder code, unfortunetly I am getting the same issue. BattleConsole should never have an empty string in it as I am always hard coding some text to add to the ArrayList before calling the CreateConsoleString() to update the TextView. I have added my code of how i add to the BattleConsole in my question. Thanks

Comment: I have added a screen shot of the issue, the scroll view sits below and above the spacer lines you can see. Thanks

Comment: What does your list contain if you debug into your application before the BattleConsole loop?

Comment: it starts as an empty ArrayList, however the CreateConsoleString() is never called until some text has actually been added to the ArrayList. Therefore, where the BattleConsole loop is called there will alyways be at least 1 item.

Comment: 1 thing I have noticed is that if I remove 'android:layout_gravity="bottom" from my TextView XML then the spacing issue is no longer there. However the scroll view no longer automatically scrolls to the bottom of the view.

Comment: Then it is a layout problem. You may check out the documentation of gravity I haven't used it myself.